# How can I fill a column with values that are computed between two dates in pandas, with a delay of one row, respecting certain conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

| Date | Distance | Position | TrainerID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-09-03 | 1000 | 2 | 6529 |
| 2017-09-03 | 1600 | 4 | 6529 |
| 2017-09-03 | 1200 | 3 | 6529 |
| 2017-09-06 | 1200 | 13 | 6529 |
| 2017-09-08 | 1000 | 1 | 6529 |
| 2017-09-10 | 1600 | 9 | 6529 |
| 2017-09-15 | 1600 | 2 | 6529 |

I want to compute on every row the winning percentage so far for the sprint races (distance of 1200 meters or less) in the last 1000 days, grouped by `TrainerID`. The result will be stored in a `Win%` Column. Dates need not to be unique. However, the winning % is considered to be before the race happened, so the current row is excluded. Thus, the results are delayed by one row.

The rows of the races that do not fit this category, should have the winning percentage from above.

What I am looking for is a result like this:

| Date | Distance | Position | TrainerID | Win % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-09-03 | 1000 | 2 | 6529 | 0 (0 wins, 0 races) |
| 2017-09-03 | 1600 | 4 | 6529 | 0 (does not fit the criteria, value copied from above) |
| 2017-09-03 | 1200 | 3 | 6529 | 0 (0 wins, 1 race) |
| 2017-09-06 | 1200 | 13 | 6529 | 0 (0 wins, 2 races) |
| 2017-09-08 | 1000 | 1 | 6529 | 0 (0 wins, 3 races) |
| 2017-09-10 | 1600 | 9 | 6529 | 25 (1 win, 4 races) |
| 2017-09-15 | 1600 | 2 | 6529 | 25 (does not fit the criteria, value copied from above) |

For this, I know I am going to need a mask to select the data that fits and, of course, the selecting code. What I have so far is this:

```
mask = (df.Distance == 1000) | (df.Distance == 1200)
df = (df.loc[mask].set_index('Date').groupby('TrainerID').rolling(no_days)['Position'].apply(lambda s:round(s.eq(1).sum()/len(s)*100)).groupby('TrainerID').shift().values)
```

The problem is that I get a dimensional mismatch error: **Length of values (12521) does not match length of index (27008)**

The selection is correct, I have problems with the mask. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to add a temporary column to calculate the winning probability.

In my environment, the following code works fine.

### Code

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

# create a sample dataframe (a markdown table is shown below as input dataframe)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: Timestamp('2017-09-08 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2017-09-05 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2017-09-04 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2017-09-15 00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2017-09-05 00:00:00'), 5: Timestamp('2017-09-11 00:00:00'), 6: Timestamp('2017-09-03 00:00:00'), 7: Timestamp('2017-09-03 00:00:00'), 8: Timestamp('2017-09-07 00:00:00'), 9: Timestamp('2017-09-07 00:00:00'), 10: Timestamp('2017-09-10 00:00:00'), 11: Timestamp('2017-09-14 00:00:00'), 12: Timestamp('2017-09-09 00:00:00'), 13: Timestamp('2017-09-11 00:00:00'), 14: Timestamp('2017-09-12 00:00:00'), 15: Timestamp('2017-09-01 00:00:00'), 16: Timestamp('2017-09-16 00:00:00'), 17: Timestamp('2017-09-15 00:00:00'), 18: Timestamp('2017-09-03 00:00:00'), 19: Timestamp('2017-09-02 00:00:00'), 20: Timestamp('2017-09-06 00:00:00')}, 'Distance': {0: 1000, 1: 1600, 2: 1000, 3: 1600, 4: 1200, 5: 1600, 6: 1600, 7: 1000, 8: 1200, 9: 1000, 10: 1600, 11: 1600, 12: 1000, 13: 1000, 14: 1600, 15: 1200, 16: 1000, 17: 1200, 18: 1200, 19: 1600, 20: 1200}, 'Position': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 1, 6: 4, 7: 2, 8: 1, 9: 2, 10: 9, 11: 9, 12: 1, 13: 1, 14: 9, 15: 10, 16: 2, 17: 2, 18: 3, 19: 9, 20: 13}, 'TrainerID': {0: 6529, 1: 1234, 2: 1234, 3: 6529, 4: 1234, 5: 1234, 6: 6529, 7: 6529, 8: 1234, 9: 9999, 10: 6529, 11: 9999, 12: 9999, 13: 9999, 14: 1234, 15: 9999, 16: 1234, 17: 9999, 18: 6529, 19: 9999, 20: 6529}})

# ensure that rows of the same Trainer ID stack in a single block, not seperately.
df = df.sort_values(['TrainerID', 'Date'], kind='stable')

# determine a window size for time series
no_days = '1000D'

# create a mask
mask = (df.Distance == 1000) | (df.Distance == 1200)

# add a temporary column for calculation
df = df.assign(Position_for_calc=df.loc[mask, 'Position'])

# use Date as index
df = df.set_index('Date')

# define calculation of win
calc = lambda s: round(100*s.eq(1).sum()/s.notnull().sum())

# obtain pd.series of calculated winning probability
ser_win = df.groupby('TrainerID').rolling(no_days)['Position_for_calc'].apply(calc).groupby('TrainerID').shift().fillna(0).values

# add Win column and drop the temporary column (a markdown table is shown below as output dataframe)
df = df.assign(Win=ser_win).drop('Position_for_calc', axis=1)
```

If you want to squeeze everything into a few lines,

```py
df = df.sort_values(['TrainerID', 'Date'], kind='stable')
df = df.assign(Win=df.assign(Position_for_calc=df.loc[(df.Distance == 1000) | (df.Distance == 1200), 'Position']).set_index('Date').groupby('TrainerID').rolling('1000D')['Position_for_calc'].apply(lambda s: round(100*s.eq(1).sum()/s.notnull().sum())).groupby('TrainerID').shift().fillna(0).values)
```

### Python Version

3.9.10

### Pandas Version

1.3.5

### Input Dataframe

|  | Date | Distance | Position | TrainerID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2017-09-08 00:00:00 | 1000 | 1 | 6529 |
| 1 | 2017-09-05 00:00:00 | 1600 | 1 | 1234 |
| 2 | 2017-09-04 00:00:00 | 1000 | 1 | 1234 |
| 3 | 2017-09-15 00:00:00 | 1600 | 2 | 6529 |
| 4 | 2017-09-05 00:00:00 | 1200 | 3 | 1234 |
| 5 | 2017-09-11 00:00:00 | 1600 | 1 | 1234 |
| 6 | 2017-09-03 00:00:00 | 1600 | 4 | 6529 |
| 7 | 2017-09-03 00:00:00 | 1000 | 2 | 6529 |
| 8 | 2017-09-07 00:00:00 | 1200 | 1 | 1234 |
| 9 | 2017-09-07 00:00:00 | 1000 | 2 | 9999 |
| 10 | 2017-09-10 00:00:00 | 1600 | 9 | 6529 |
| 11 | 2017-09-14 00:00:00 | 1600 | 9 | 9999 |
| 12 | 2017-09-09 00:00:00 | 1000 | 1 | 9999 |
| 13 | 2017-09-11 00:00:00 | 1000 | 1 | 9999 |
| 14 | 2017-09-12 00:00:00 | 1600 | 9 | 1234 |
| 15 | 2017-09-01 00:00:00 | 1200 | 10 | 9999 |
| 16 | 2017-09-16 00:00:00 | 1000 | 2 | 1234 |
| 17 | 2017-09-15 00:00:00 | 1200 | 2 | 9999 |
| 18 | 2017-09-03 00:00:00 | 1200 | 3 | 6529 |
| 19 | 2017-09-02 00:00:00 | 1600 | 9 | 9999 |
| 20 | 2017-09-06 00:00:00 | 1200 | 13 | 6529 |

### Output Dataframe

| Date | Distance | Position | TrainerID | Win |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-09-04 00:00:00 | 1000 | 1 | 1234 | 0 |
| 2017-09-05 00:00:00 | 1600 | 1 | 1234 | 100 |
| 2017-09-05 00:00:00 | 1200 | 3 | 1234 | 100 |
| 2017-09-07 00:00:00 | 1200 | 1 | 1234 | 50 |
| 2017-09-11 00:00:00 | 1600 | 1 | 1234 | 67 |
| 2017-09-12 00:00:00 | 1600 | 9 | 1234 | 67 |
| 2017-09-16 00:00:00 | 1000 | 2 | 1234 | 67 |
| 2017-09-03 00:00:00 | 1600 | 4 | 6529 | 0 |
| 2017-09-03 00:00:00 | 1000 | 2 | 6529 | 0 |
| 2017-09-03 00:00:00 | 1200 | 3 | 6529 | 0 |
| 2017-09-06 00:00:00 | 1200 | 13 | 6529 | 0 |
| 2017-09-08 00:00:00 | 1000 | 1 | 6529 | 0 |
| 2017-09-10 00:00:00 | 1600 | 9 | 6529 | 25 |
| 2017-09-15 00:00:00 | 1600 | 2 | 6529 | 25 |
| 2017-09-01 00:00:00 | 1200 | 10 | 9999 | 0 |
| 2017-09-02 00:00:00 | 1600 | 9 | 9999 | 0 |
| 2017-09-07 00:00:00 | 1000 | 2 | 9999 | 0 |
| 2017-09-09 00:00:00 | 1000 | 1 | 9999 | 0 |
| 2017-09-11 00:00:00 | 1000 | 1 | 9999 | 33 |
| 2017-09-14 00:00:00 | 1600 | 9 | 9999 | 50 |
| 2017-09-15 00:00:00 | 1200 | 2 | 9999 | 50 |

Comment: I get an error message stating that: "index must be monotonic", at the `groupby` function. The dates are not sorted at this point.

Comment: In my environment, I do not get that error. I updated my answer to clarify the sample dataframe I used. Please check the code again.

Comment: I hope you paste the result of the following command in your question in order for answerers to use the same dataframe as yours : `print(df.head(30).to_dict())`

Comment: I ran the code that you provided, including the sample `df`, on the Python terminal in PyCharm and I still got the error message at the line `ser_win = df.groupby('TrainerID').rolling(no_days)['Position_for_calc'].apply(calc).groupby('TrainerID').shift().fillna(0).values`. I have Python 3.9.10 and Pandas 1.4.0.

Comment: Later edit: on Pandas 1.3.5, it works like a charm, so I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Thank you. It's surprising for me that Pandas 1.4.0 rejects this code.